# Binary Search, How many intervals content a point

Tags: python

I am trying to create a preprocessing in O(nlogn) time, given a point on the OX, I can find, in time, O(logn) at how many intervals it belongs.

Preprocessing: I've thought about sorting the list using the quicksort algorithm

Algorithm: I thought I'd do it with a binary search but it doesn't work

```
#O(logn)
def algoritmo(inter,i,j,punto):
    if i == j:
        res = -1
    else:
        p = int((i + j) / 2)
        if punto == inter[p][0]:
            res = [inter[p][0],inter[p][1]]
        elif punto <= inter[p][0]:
            res = algoritmo(inter,i,p,punto)
        else:
            res = algoritmo(inter,p,j,punto)
    return res

print(algoritmo(intervalos,0,len(intervalos),15))
```

Any recommendations? Another way to do it?

Comment: General advice: do not use recurrence in python. SO advice: explain what you mean by "OX", give example inputs for your function, and explain what you mean by "it doesn't work". Does it raise an exception? Does it output something different than you expect?

Comment: OX is x coordinate. Doesn't show the correct solution

Comment: But what are `i`, `j` and `punto`? Either way edit your question with an example function call.

Comment: @nicoco ready!.

Comment: What would be useful now is the actual content of `intervalos`, and also the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the pairs (x, num_of_segments_from_this_x_to_the_next) and do binary search for the queries.
The preprocessing can be done sorting the segments by their left endpoint and doing a sweep line over them.

Say your segments are [1,5] [2,4] [3,7]
You would save [1,1] [2,2] [3,3] [4,2] [5,1] [7,0]
where each number on the left is an x coordinate and each number on the right is how many "active" lines when walking from left to right.

Then on a query you only have to do a binary search. E.g if you want to know how many segments pass through 6 you get its position (between [5,1] and [7,0], from where you know that after 5 and up to 7 all the points intersect one line segment) and return 6. 
Of course depending on your implementation you should handle the specifics for the endpoints themselves. In my example, if you ask e.g for 4, you would have to return 3 which corresponds to the previous point, but if you ask for 3 you would return 3 (if you consider that the endpoints are in the segments). To avoid that complexity I would store also the specific responses for each endpoint, which depend on the details of the problem

Comment: Can you specify a little more?

Comment: do you understand it better now?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try something, it's in O(n). I don't really understand the need for recursion or binary search trees, but your question is not crystal clear, to say the least.

```
intervals = [[0,10],[5,12],[-4,3],[8,10]]
point = 9
result = []
for i, (lower, higher) in enumerate(intervals):
    if lower < point < higher:
        result += [i]
print(result)  # [0,1,3], i.e., point is in the first, second and fourth interval
```